# @synthesize no longer automatically added to .m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After using the connector to connect a button, text field and label the @synthesize statements are not automatically generated for the label and text field (both are outlets) and hence when I try to access the label or text feild or their properties in the .m file it says "use of undeclared identifer" but shouldn't Xcode have done that automatically? I am following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3Yd2kCPs5c (at about 4:35 it shows auto generated @synthesize statements which no longer happen in xcode) and this is what I am guessing causes this error. I shouldn't have to manually add these right? What is the best way to fix this?

```
-------.m Fie--------
//
//  ViewController.m
//  AutoConnection
//
//  Created by Administrator on 29/03/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Administrator. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", [myTextFeild text]];
    [myLabel setText:message];

}
@end

---------.h file------------
//
//  ViewController.h
//  AutoConnection
//
//  Created by Administrator on 29/03/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Administrator. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextFeild;

@end
```

Comment: Your xcode version please?

Comment: Xcode version : 4.6.1

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not on a third party site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After seeing your codes,

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextFeild;
```

You are accessng them as:

```
 [myLabel setText:message];
```

Which is incorrect.

It should be `[_myLabel setText:message];`

or `[self.myLabel setText:message];`

**Reason:** The compiler running with XCode4.4 and above, autosynthesizes your property as

```
@synthesize yourProperty=_yourProperty;
```

Or you can override this by, if you wish to use same property name

```
@synthesize yourProperty;
```

Comment: Thanks, using the "_" solves the issue, should i always do this for all calls to properties in any file?

Comment: yes, either _ or self. has to be used. self uses accessors and _ directly to the property.

Answer (score 3):

You no longer have to use `@synthesize`. It is easier now since all you have to do is add a `_` character before the property. Example

```
//header
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *l;

//implementation
-(void)viewDidLoad{
_l = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//do stuff
}
```

You could also just manually add the synthesize line

Comment: But you should only access your properties directly on your init or dealloc methods! In any other methods you should use its accessor     self.propertyName

Answer (score 2):

You need to use self for auto-synthesized property usage

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", [myTextFeild text]];
    [self.myLabel setText:message];

}
```

if you have a property named *myLabel* , the compiler will produce code as if

```
@synthesize myLabel=_myLabel;
```

With Xcode 4.4 and LLVM Compiler 4.0 the @synthesize directive is no longer required as it will be provided by default. That means in most cases you now only need the @property and the compiler takes care of everything else for you. In general the compiler will generate the instance variable automatically.

So if you want to access property you can use `self.myLabel` and for instance usage you can use `_myLabel`

Answer (score 2):

The @synthesize is now done automatically by the compiler. The @property creates a getter and setter method which can be accessed using dot-notation (e.g. self.myLabel).
These methods use a variable to store the object you are accessing. Xcode generates the variable name by adding an underscore to the property name.

Just use getters and setters and don't access an object using the instance variable (e.g. _myLabel = foo). That's bad style.

Here's a good iTunes U course covering all this: [*Coding Together: Developing Apps for iPhone and iPad*](https://itunes.apple.com/de/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016?l=en)